# jquery nth-selecting and setInterval

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, setinterval

Hey all. Basically, I want the the next image to be clicked using jquery every second:

jQuery:

```
 var i=1;

 setInterval(function() {
  $(".portfolio :nth-child("+i+")").click();
  if (i<5) {i++;} else {i=1;}

 }, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio"> 
  <ul> 
   <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="4" id="promo_one"></li> 
   <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" id="promo_two"></li> 
   <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="2" id="promo_three"></li> 
   <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="3" id="promo_four"></li> 
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And what's the problem you're having?

Comment: This isn't even a question and therefore, voting to close.

Comment: Ok if you're going to be pedantic, then question can be: "Why doesn't this work?" ¬_¬  Thanks everyone for so many answers, many of the below work :)

Comment: pedantry has nothing to do with it.  When you don't accurately describe the problem, its very difficult to know which answers are going to be the correct solutions and then deserving answers don't get upvoted because of the confusion. Also, many "why doesn't this work?" questions get closed for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) you can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) here, like this:

```
var i=1;
setInterval(function() {
  $(".portfolio ul li img").eq(i).click();
  i = i==3 ? 0 : i + 1;
}, 1000);
```

Your selector should also go down to the `<img>` (or leave out the `img` part if you want to click the `<li>`), otherwise you're clicking other elements as well.  This gets all images, and grabs the one at the index you want using [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) so you can [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) it.

Comment: +1 - This solution would be especially good/efficient if you cache the set. Just one lookup, and all index references henceforth.

Answer (score 1):

I think your selector should be:

```
$(".portfolio > ul > li:nth-child("+i+")").click();
```

...e.g., you're looking for the *nth* `li` that's a child of a `ul` that's a child of a `.portfolio`. Those are child selectors. You could probably use a descendant selector instead, but I think (supposition) that child selectors will be a bit more efficient as they have less searching to do. (Of course, they'll also be more brittle, if you change your structure.)

See also [patrick's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085450/jquery-nth-selecting-and-setinterval/3085502#3085502) about your `i<4` comparision, it's probably off by one.

Comment: +1 This was certainly the main issue. The index was the first thing that caught my eye, but the code would have been functional with that error give your proper selector.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check if `i` is less than `4` since you have 4 links.

```
if (i<4) {i++;} else {i=1;}
```

Since `:nth-child` is a `1` based index, and `4` is less than `5`, when you get to `4`, it is being increment to `5`, but there is no `:nth-child(5)`.

As others noted, you want to specify the `:nth-child` on the correct element as well.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JBt6b/

Comment: And pretty much everyone else missed that bit. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I edited that before you submitted your post. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: it wouldn't throw an error though, would it? jQuery returns an empty jQuery object when it doesn't "find" anything, so it should mean that for 1 iteration, a click is triggered on a non-existent object.  It doesn't help that the question doesn't even describe the problem, so it's hard to know which answers to upvote when there are so many!

Comment: @Andy - Yeah, the index issue would not stop the code from running. There's just an extra 1 second pause when you get to the unmatched index.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=1;

setInterval(function(){
   $('.portfolio').find('img[alt=' + i + ']').trigger('click');
   if(i < 4) i++; else i=1;
}, 1000);
```

By looking up the ALT attribute, this task has a better performance (like a lot).
Makes only sense if the ALT attribute is always present of course.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your javascript code like so:

```
var i=1;

setInterval(function() {
  $(".portfolio ul :nth-child("+i+")").click();

  if (i<5) {i++;} else {i=1;}

}, 1000);
```

In your example `.portfolio` does not have n Children, it has 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close(I'm not sure exactly what isn't working), but you may want to change your selector from:

```
".portfolio :nth-child("+i+")"
```

to:

```
".portfolio ul li:nth-child("+i+")"
```

if you are looking to select the nth li element.  I'm not sure what else is wrong with the code, please expand on your question if this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would precompute many of the items and use modular arithmetic to rotate through the images.

```
var images = $('.portfolio img').;
var count = images.length;
var lastClicked = count - 1;

setInterval( function() {
    var next = ++lastClicked % count;
    images.eq(next).click();
}, 1000);
```